# How to print all Mondays in a month of may-2020

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select next_day(to_date('01-may-20','dd-mon-yy')-1,'monday')+7*(level-1)
from dual 
connect by level<=4;
```

Comment: This is an Oracle query. Have you tried anything? In general, [a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with extensive indexing makes date queries a *lot* easier and faster, better than any tricks based on indexes and numbers. With it, you can just write `select date from Calendar where Year=2020 and Month=5 and WeekDay=1` or `WeekDay='Monday'`. If the calendar table contains a Year-Month column, the query becomes even sorter

Comment: Select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1,'monday')+7*(level-1) from dual connect by level<=4;

Comment: I repeat, that's an Oracle query. Have you tried anything yourself? Or are you asking people to translate the query for you?

Comment: @Preethi Because of the way you tagged this question, you have created a confusing question. Do you want the query to work on Microsoft SQL Server? Or was the wrong tag applied? Please let us know what sort of help you are looking for.

Comment: Ya it is an oracle SQL query , u r right..!

Comment: In my query instead of mentioning 4 to level , I want to execute that query in some other way sir

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive approach if you want just look at the specific month :

```
with cte as (
     select convert(date, '2020-05-01') as startdate
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, startdate)
     from cte c
     where c.startdate < '2020-05-31'
)
select c.startdate as Mondays
from cte c
where (datepart(WEEKDAY, c.startdate) + 5) % 7 + 1  = 1;
```

Comment: You can use `EOMONTH` to remove the second hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all the mondays on the month starting at the @day variable.

```
declare @day date = '2020-05-01';

with cte as (
  select @day as day
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, day) 
  from cte
  where month(dateadd(day, 1, day)) = month(day)
)
select * 
from cte 
where datepart(weekday, day) = 2
```

It's recursive, you start with the @day variable, and add one day consecutively while you remain on the same month. Once this CTE returns all the days of the month, you filter it returning the days of the weekday 2 (this functions starts the week on Sunday as day 1).

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
Select to_date('01-MAY-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + (level-1)
from dual 
where ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('01-MAY-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + (level-1), 'Day'))) = 
'Monday'
connect by level<=31;
```

1. Date is taken as '01-MAY-2020' as you requested
2. In WHERE Clause, date is converted to day and filtered out for Monday alone

Comment: And Preethi this an Oracle query, please tag your question as Oracle